# Can't connect to MySQLA database in Groovy

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, groovy

I have this small code :

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
class GroovySqlExample1{
  static void main(String[] args) {
    def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost/jdb", "root",
           "root", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    sql.eachRow("select * from user"){ row ->
       //other code . . . . 
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the following code with the :

```
 groovy -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar database.groovy
```

I get this big error:

```
Caught: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2332)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at GroovySqlExample1.main(database.groovy:4)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:294)
    ... 9 more
```

Note that, I can log into mysql as :

```
 mysql -u root -proot -hlocalhost
```

Everything seems to be fine. But still I get those errors. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. Where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: Can you try with the v5.1.21 driver?

Comment: What version of mysql are you running?

Comment: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.24, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2`

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql

Comment: Yup, but unlucky! Didn't find a solution. I guess my firewall is playing in the scene. Have to check that out.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify port number for your MySQL DB as JDBC never knows which port number is used for each types of DBs. For MySQL, I believe default port number should be set as 3306